# Voltage Amplifier - Using a

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-design, dc, voltage-amplification

[image: I am looking to build a DC voltage amplifier. In this picture, I am using a 2N3904 NPN transistors. Does this work as a DC voltage amplifier?]

[image]
I am looking to build a DC voltage amplifier. In this picture, I am using a 2N3904 NPN transistors. Does this work as a DC voltage amplifier? Does it make sense?

If this doesn't work, how do I make a DC voltage amplifier?? Thank you!

Comment: No, it does not work as a voltage amplifier. No, it does not make sense. It burns the transistor up in smoke. Have you done any research before asking, like putting "transistor voltage amplifier" into your favourite search engine?

Comment: Kind of what I thought. I have been trying to do some research but it seems that each of the amplifiers also requires an AC input signal. I currently do not have access to that so I need a strictly DC voltage amplifier.

Comment: @Justme: It does not burn the transistor into smoke, it depends on the input voltage at the R2 - smile :-)

Comment: Hi CPK. If you don't put a resistor series to the transistor to limit current, then It will blow up the transistor.

Comment: An op-amp might work but what is it that you are trying to amplify or connect together? You may have a X-Y problem; you might think you need a voltage amplifier to solve a problem, so you ask about them, but perhaps a voltage amplifier does not solve your problem at all. Tell us more info what is the input and output of that circuit going to.

Comment: @TomKuschel 862mV is shown at the base, it should be enough to turn that into a Smoke Emitting Transistor.

Comment: The input to that transistor is a MOSFET logic circuit. The MOSFET logic is determining if light is present or not. When light is present, I am wanting to activate a 555-timer. That's why I am needing to amplify the DC voltage so that I can activate the 555-timer.

Comment: How would you know that connecting a transistor does not prevent the original circuit from operating, due to the extra current draw of the transistor? Why can't you directly connect them without a transistor? Do you need the transistor to invert the signal? The CMOS 555 input takes virtually no current. Show the bigger picture from where the signal comes from, and where it goes.

Comment: I updated the picture on the original post.

Comment: As I suspected - you don't need a voltage amplifier. Will write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is... incomplete. You need a couple of things to make this work:

- a load resistor on the transistor
- some negative feedback to control the gain (if required)

If you want to play around with this kind of a circuit, try the "common emitter" amplifier on Falstad, here: http://www.falstad.com/circuit/ and select the Circuits->Transistors->Common-Emitter Amplifier pulldown.

Here's an edited Falstad example that shows a [simple voltage translator / inverter from 3.3V to 9V](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2016.13108636308289%2060%2015%2053%0Aw%20288%2048%20336%2048%200%0Ar%20160%20224%20240%20224%200%2010000%0At%20240%20224%20336%20224%200%201%20-8.999999997%209.999999996133773e-10%20100%0Ag%20336%20240%20336%20272%200%0AR%20288%2048%20192%2048%200%200%2040%209%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20336%2048%20336%20208%200%2010000%0AR%20160%20224%20112%20224%200%202%2080%201.6%201.6%200%200.5%0AO%20336%20208%20400%20208%200%0Ao%206%2064%200%204098%205%200.00009765625%200%202%206%203%0Ao%207%2064%200%204098%2010%200.00009765625%201%201%0A).

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, you do not want a voltage amplifier, you want to use a transistor as a switch.

So, you want NE555 to be on, when LED is on, so basically when Q2 output is low.

Put a PNP transistor or a P-FET to act as a switch.

In case of PNP transistor, emitter to VCC, collector to drive power to NE555, and say 1k base resistor to Q2 output.

If you use a P-FET, Source to VCC, Drain to power NE555, and you don't even need a resistor to connect FET gate to Q2 output.

Comment: Thank you so much. I implemented your changes and it worked perfectly as the switch I Needed. I used the P-FET method just because I have on in my lab kit.